# Can thread safety ever be ignored?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

Educating myself on the topic of threads. Thus far from what I've been able to gather, if a program isn't thread-safe, and concurrent reads/writes occur, it is likely to result in unintended effects.

However, suppose perfect accuracy didn't matter? Say you're polling mouse coordinates in one thread, and your main thread reads these values, without locking. You might not get perfectly accurate results (a potential mix of new and old data), but provided the polling is fast enough, the inaccuracy should be imperceptible to the user. Does it matter that the method isn't thread safe? Can it cause any other issues?

Comment: Polling for mouse coordinates is a bad example because it's too linear, i.e. easy to accomplish with a single thread. Threads are best used for problems that benefit from a [divide and conquer approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know what the result will be, and have no way to tell if it actually is close to the expected value. Say the X position of the mouse is store in 2 bytes, but your system can only write one byte atomically. Then if the actual value changes behind your back from 255 to 256 (`0x00FF` to `0x0100`) there would be an internal step, `0x00FF -> 0x01FF -> 0x0100` (or similar), that you can read from unknowingly. Then you would think your x-value is 511 not 256 which is a significant difference, not just a few pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse coordinates are not updated atomically, then you may get values that could be invalid.

For example, if a long value representing the x co-ordinate is not updated atomically than the value you read could be invalid.